# fopen() memory leak after few hundred runs

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, memory-leaks, fopen

I'm writing an application which should read some data at some level from a file. When I run the code (including fopen() and fclose())for more than a few hundred times, I got the error message (which I know it means that it cannot open the file):

Debug Assertaion Failed!
Program:
D:\blahblah
file: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtwin32\stdio\fgets.c
Line: 57
Expression: (string!=NULL)

Can you please help me to understand why it should break after more than three hundered time?

```
 Func_Main(char * filePath, ...){
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){ 
        Func_1(filePath);
        ....
    }
     ....
 }

 Func_1(char* filepath){
       char   buffer[1024];
       FILE * file= NULL;
       file = fopen(filepath, "r");
       while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file)){
             \\ do something
       }
       fclose(file);
 }
```

Comment: Because `fopen()` failed, and your code doesn't check the return value like it should?

Comment: @EOF It looks like as the error says that it could not open the file! You mean it should be fgets()?

Comment: Strange: you get a `filepath` as parameter but you open a static filename. Whatever checking for `fopen` success is an must-add.

Comment: @EOF `fopen` return is being checked I  think , see `while` loop condition .

Comment: @ameyCU: Are you seeing the same code I see? `while(fgets())` has *nothing* to do with checking the return value of `fopen()`.

Comment: No, `fgets` return is checked. But if `fgets` is called on a non-opened `FILE*` what happens? Probably UB or error.

Comment: @EOF Ohh , my bad , I saw that as `,` operatore and file descriptor differently . Sorry for that .

Comment: @ameyCU: even `while (fgets(), file)` would be completely wrong, since it too would try to `fgets()` from a `NULL` filepointer *before* the check.

Comment: @hexasoft I edited the code, in fact I have used the argument! But why should I got error after 300 times?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the return value of `fopen`. It will return a null pointer if opening the file failed.

And it will fail because `\` is an escape character , use `\\` in the filename string.

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

1. You never use the argument passed to `Func_1`. You use a hard coded path instead.
2. The hard coded path has an error. You are not escaping the backslash in the hard coded path . It should be:

   ```
   file = fopen("c:\\blahblah.txt", "r");
                   ^^
   ```
3. You are not checking whether `fopen` was successful. You are assuming it was successful. Use:

   ```
   file = fopen("c:\\blahblah.txt", "r");
   if ( file == NULL )
   {
      // Deal with the error.
      perror("Unable to open the file");
   }
   ```

**Update, after the OP edited the question**

The first two points can be ignored. The last point still needs to be considered.

```
file = fopen(filepath, "r");
if ( file == NULL )
{
   // Deal with the error.
   perror("Unable to open the file");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited it in fact I have used the argument!

Comment: And are you sure you're not misusing \ at the point where the argument is set now?